# getting access token after signing up in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, reactjs-native

Is it possible to get access token immediately after signing up a user in loopback without having to log in the user? If so how do you go about that? Am using loopback 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current snippet.
You need to add a custom remote method in your **`common/models/account.js`** file (or whatever name you choose) where your `Account` Model [inherits](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Customizing-models.html#extending-another-model) the built-in `User` Model:

```
module.exports = function (Account) {

        Account.createAndLogin = function (data, cb) {
            if (!data || !data.password) {
                return cb(new Error("Attribute 'password' is mandatory to create a new user."));
            }
            Account.create(data, function (err, account) {
                if (err) {
                    return cb(err, null);
                }
                Account.login({email: data.email, password: data.password}, function (err, token) {
                    if (err) {
                        return cb(err, null);
                    }
                    cb(err, {
                        id: token.id,
                        ttl: token.ttl,
                        created: token.created,
                        userId: token.userId,
                        account: account
                    });
                });
            });
        };

        Account.remoteMethod('createAndLogin', {
            description: "Create and login in one remote method",
            accepts: {arg: 'data', type: 'object', required: true, http: {source: 'body'}, description: 'Model instance data'},
            returns: {arg: 'accessToken', type: 'object', root: true, description: 'User Model'},
            http: {verb: 'post'}
        });
};
```

Edit: Since the `Account` Model inherits the built-in `User` Model, you need to open the Access Control Lists (**ACLs**) to **$everyone**.

So your  **`common/models/account.json`** file should look like this:

```
{
  "name": "Account",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "createAndLogin"
    }
  ],
  "methods": []
}
```

Comment: when I use your method and try to create a user(in my case student) I get Authorization required error...How did you set the AccessToken?

Comment: Since it inherits the built-in User Model, you need to open your ACLs to everyone for this new remote method. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an [after remote hook](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html) to the `users/create` remote method, so after it's successfully called you can call User.login() (to get the access token) with the password that you probably can get from the `request` object. So after register request, you'd get the access token in the response.